# PHP Web Crawler MultiThreaded Support

Tags: php

I want to make a website crawler using only PHP. I want to make it multithreaded as well not to be really slow.

I can use either pthreads xtension from here http://pthreads.org/ or pcntl_fork()

The question is how i am going to implement such a feature. Can someone explain me how i can achieve this using PHP or a diagram or something?

I know PHP, so just focus on the algorithm. I just need ideas

Thank you

Comment: There is a pthreads extension as i said above. It's not real pthreads but still it works

Comment: Why not to use `curl_multi` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-add-handle.php) instead of PHP multithreading?

Comment: curl_multi will only multi thread the requests and not the actual parsing. Might be enough though... You can of course also curl_multi request your crawler, which then only requests one page and parses it.

Comment: pthreads *is* real threading @ToBe curl multi is *not* multi-threaded, it is non-blocking ...

Comment: I never doubted that. It just might not be available for everyone.